# Symfony 4 routing: multiple params with multiple slashes?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I've been trying to make this work for a while, without much luck:

```
file_show:
    path: /{user}/file/{group}/{file}
    controller: Acme\Controller\File::show
    requirements:
        group: .+
        file: .+


# /john/file/acme/group/test/file.zip
# user: john
# group: acme/group
# file: test/file.zip
```

Does the Symfony Router support multiple params with multiple slashes like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No symfony does not support multiple params with slashes straight after each other as ist can not know where one parameter ends and the next one begins.

```
# /john/file/acme/group/test/file.zip
# user: john
# group: acme/group             
# file: test/file.zip
```

could also be

```
# /john/file/acme/group/test/file.zip
# user: john
# group: acme             
# file: group/test/file.zip
```

You can work around this by using a different sign between the params and not allow that sign inside the params. [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/slash_in_parameter.html)